# Como converter data para um component Angular?

Tags: angular

Tenho esta data no formato de string:

```
Sun May 16 2021 09:54:25 GMT-0300 (Horário Padrão de Brasília)
```

E quero inseri-la no formulário do front-end:

```
<div class="ui-grid-col-6">
      <vale-calendar  [showTime]="true" [showSeconds]="true"
          [showIcon]="false" formControlName="dataFim" [locale]="appService.locale" icon="fa fa-calendar" name="dataFim"></vale-calendar>
</div>
```

Para colocar o valor no formulário estou usando o valor de element.value. O valor de element.label é dataFim

```
element.value === null ? this.form.controls[element.label].setValue(null) : this.form.controls[element.label].setValue(element.value);
```

Erro obtido:

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Missing number at position 0

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 0):

tudo certo?

Infelizmente faltam algumas informações para te ajudar com um pouco mais de detalhe, mas vou tentar te ajudar mesmo assim.

O que seria esse `element.value`? Ele é uma propriedade da classe?

Além disso, seria necessário verificar o formato de data que esse componente `vale-calendar` recebe. Pode ser que ele precise receber essa informação em um formato diferente do qual você está passando. Se esse for o caso, você pode usar os métodos disponíveis na api de `Date` do próprio JavaScript para formatar essa data.

Espero ter ajudado um pouco.

Abraço!